# add two different query in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, postgresql

I want to add two query but its not working. Here's my

Model page:

```
 public function updateTable(){

 $first=  $this->db->query("select column1 from table where table_id='data1' AND 
    field_id=6"); // Data type is numeric. When I query this, result is 0.0

 $second=  $this->db->query("select column1 from table where table_id='data2' AND 
    field_id=6"); // Data type is numeric also. When I query this, result is 0.0 also

 $total=$first+$second;

 }
```

When I try to run this I got an error message

```
Message: Object of class CI_DB_postgre_result could not be converted to int
```

How can I make this happen or is this possible?

EDIT: NEW INFO

I want to use this $total to an if statement .

```
 if ($total==0){
 //code here
 }
```

What should I do?

Comment: What is data1 ? Is it an integer?

Comment: @Vinod VT numeric data type. If its 1 in integer, its 1.0 in numeric. I think they're just the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's see the first example in CI userguide: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
  echo $row->title;
  echo $row->name;
  echo $row->body;
}
```

we learn two things:

1. `$this->db->query("YOUR QUERY")` does not return a result, `$query->result()` does.
2. the result is an array of object. object names is the column name.

if you're sure every query only return one result. you can change your code like this:

```
$first=  $this->db->query("select column1 from table where table_id='data1' AND 
field_id=6")->result()[0]->column1; 

$second=  $this->db->query("select column1 from table where table_id='data2' AND 
field_id=6")->result()[0]->column1;
```

===== answer been revised below =====

**The analysis is correct but code above throws error, because php regard result()[0] as a whole.**

you can either separate them

```
$row = $this->db->query("select column1 from table where table_id='data1' AND 
field_id=6")->result();
$first = $row[0]->column1;
```

or use [current](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.current.php/) function

```
  $first=  current($this->db->query("select column1 from table where table_id='data1' AND 
field_id=6")->result())->column1;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
 $total=$first->column1 + $second->column1;
```

Comment: it's not working. The new error message is Message: Undefined property: CI_DB_postgre_result::$column1.....

Comment: try this $total=$first->row()->column1 + $second->row()->column1;

Comment: The error message is Message: Undefined property: CI_DB_postgre_result::$column1

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the total result num, it will be

```
$first->num_rows() + $second->num_rows()
```

If to get all the result, then

```
array_merge ( $first->result (), $second->result );
```

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html

Answer (score 0):

This process incorrect,  the query return **MYSql Result Object** that wont add.

Do you want to sum (column1) values,

you can add column value in sql query, try this way

```
public function updateTable(){

 $first=  $this->db->query("select column1 from table where table_id='data1' AND 
    field_id=6"); // Data type is numeric. When I query this, result is 0.0

 $second=  $this->db->query("select column1 from table where table_id='data2' AND 
    field_id=6"); // Data type is numeric also. When I query this, result is 0.0 also

 $total=$first->row()->column1 + $second->row()->column1;

 }
```

OR

```
  public function updateTable(){

     $total_result=  $this->db->query("select SUM(column1) as sum_column1 from table where table_id IN('data1', 'data2') AND 
        field_id=6"); // Data type is numeric. When I query this, result is 0.0

     echo $total_result->row()->sum_column1;


     }
```

Comment: I tried your above answer but it says column1 is undefined variable.

Comment: the query return empty result so you have get `column1` variable,

Comment: @Kino **"select column1 from table where table_id='data1' AND 
    field_id=6"** run the query and make sure the return result?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code i think this will work

```
public function updateTable(){

 $first=  $this->db->query("select column1 from table where table_id='data1' AND 
    field_id=6")->row(); // Data type is numeric. When I query this, result is 0.0

 $second=  $this->db->query("select column1 from table where table_id='data2' AND 
    field_id=6")->row(); // Data type is numeric also. When I query this, result is 0.0 also

 $total=$first+$second;

 }
```

Comment: just add row() in the last query